# Sustituir palabras iguales en toda la página con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Busco sustituir o reemplazar todas las palabras iguales de un documento web, es decir de todo el DOM. En el avance (ejemplo) podrán ver que solo reemplaza la primera palabra y no las otras del mismo contenido. Tengo un segundo problema que, al incorporar esta acción, el menú responsivo se duplica de manera intermitente cada segundo.

El objetivo es, reemplazar todas las palabras iguales del DOM con la ayuda de Javascript, Jquery o alguna otra opción. De antemano, quedo agradecida.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body *").html(function(buscayreemplaza, reemplaza) {
    return reemplaza.replace('de', ' <strong>para</strong> ');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Titulo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    Este "de" es la que cambió y este "de" no cambia.
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      Una sección de contenido de bloque.
      <article>
        Primer artículo de la página de Miriam.
      </article>
      <article>
        Segundo artículo de la página de Miriam.
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <aside>
    Aquí los widget de Miriam y los usuarios de su negocio.
  </aside>
  <footer>
    El pie de la página de Miriam.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A parte de la respuesta, si estás buscando la solución con jQuery, aquí tienes otro enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `.replaceAll()` para aplicar el cambio en todas las coincidencias, solo hay que tener en cuenta que también puede afectar donde probablemente no debería, incluso en etiquetas como `header` o `theader`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Obtener todas las etiquetas de document.body
  let tags = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
  // Aplicar remplazo
  tags.forEach(tag => tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.replaceAll('de', ' <strong>para</strong> '));
});
```

```css
table {
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Titulo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    Este "de" es la que cambió y este "de" ya cambia, aunque este también coincide y lo afecta.
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      Una sección de contenido de bloque.
      <article>
        Primer artículo de la página de Miriam.
      </article>
      <article>
        Segundo artículo de la página de Miriam.
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <aside>
    Aquí los widget de Miriam y los usuarios de su negocio.
  </aside>
  <table>
    <theader>
      <tr>
        <th>Usa el inspector del navegador<br>en el título de la tabla</th>
      </tr>
    </theader>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cuerpo de la tabla</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <footer>
    El pie de la página de Miriam.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

En cuanto a tu otro problema:

> Tengo un segundo problema que, al incorporar esta acción, el menú responsivo se duplica de manera intermitente cada segundo.

No creo que remplazar unas palabras por otras sean la causa y te recomiendo crear otra pregunta donde expongas lo que pasa, incluyendo el código necesario para un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).